# Add script tag before closing body on every page

Tags: oracle-apex

I have some JavaScript that I would like to add to the bottom of every page right before the closing script tag.  I tried doing it in Page 0 as a new region, however, I could not absolutely position the region, no matter what I tried the content would always be rendered a few lines before the closing form tag. (region 5)

I just need the following to be on every page:

```
   <script src="#WORKSPACE_IMAGES#bundle.min.js"></script>  
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add an HTML code to every page is to put it in a page template. Go to `Shared Components` -> `Templates`, find your template, switch to `Definition` tab, and add your code in any place you like.